# Laravel 4: Jasper Reports plugin for PHP not working in the program code

Tags: php, laravel-4, jasper-reports

I am using JasperPHP plugin that i found in this link https://github.com/cossou/JasperPHP.

*`From their website:
The JasperReports Library is the world's most popular open source reporting engine. It is entirely written in Java and it is able to use data coming from any kind of data source and produce pixel-perfect documents that can be viewed, printed or exported in a variety of document formats including HTML, PDF, Excel, OpenOffice and Word.*

I used the following code to compile a jrxml file

```
JasperPHP::compile(base_path() . '/vendor/cossou/jasperphp/examples/hello_world.jrxml', false, false, false)->execute();
```

When i run this in the command line using the `php artisan tinker` a .jasper file was generated as expected. but when i put this in the program code under the routes.php, it throws an error.

```
Route::get('/', function(){
    JasperPHP::compile(base_path() . '/vendor/cossou/jasperphp/examples/hello_world.jrxml', false, false, false)->execute();
});
```

According to the log file:

```
[2015-01-17 16:51:02] production.ERROR: exception 'Exception' with message 'There was and error executing the report! Time to check the logs!' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/jasperTry/vendor/cossou/jasperphp/src/JasperPHP/JasperPHP.php:130
Stack trace:
#0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/jasperTry/app/routes.php(17): JasperPHP\JasperPHP->execute()
#1 [internal function]: {closure}()
#2 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/jasperTry/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(109): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#3 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/jasperTry/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(1028): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#4 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/jasperTry/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(996): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#5 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/jasperTry/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(775): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#6 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/jasperTry/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(745): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#7 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/jasperTry/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware.php(72): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#8 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/jasperTry/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Queue.php(47): Illuminate\Session\Middleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#9 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/jasperTry/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Guard.php(51): Illuminate\Cookie\Queue->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#10 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/jasperTry/vendor/stack/builder/src/Stack/StackedHttpKernel.php(23): Illuminate\Cookie\Guard->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#11 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/jasperTry/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(641): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#12 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/jasperTry/public/index.php(49): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run()
#13 {main} [] []
```

What could be the problem here? Thank in advance.

Comment: Could be a file permission issue. You could try putting the `.jrxml` in `app/storage` (which should have chmod 777)

Comment: thanks @lukasgeiter .. but it still works for the php artisan tinker only

Comment: Do you really need to compile jrxml with your Php app? I suggest you to use Jasper Studio or Ireports to design, validate and compile report, keeping external vendor responsability on this task. Then set up JasperServer and upload your compiled report, based on same external vendor principle, and finally use it in your app as a service (JasperServer have REST and  SOAP APIs). With this you will give Jasper all their responsabilities on reports management and your app will be a client of these services, keeping loose coupling and avoiding strong dependences

Comment: hi @Alejandro , thanks for you suggestions , yes i could let the report do the compilation.. but i need to generate the report within my php app which have the same method of executing as the above sample.. my problem is that it throws an error when i try to execute them in the php app, but works in php artisan tinker..